# Why wp_mail() function returns 'false'?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a contact form that gets from ajax parameters and uses them to send emails. 
The function is located in functions.php of my child theme for twentyfifteen:

```
// Contact form  Ajax 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_contact_form', 'submit_contact_form'); 

function submit_contact_form(){

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];       
        $email_to = "wawd@company.pro";

        $email_subject = "You have a new email from $email via yyy.com website";
        $message = $_POST['text']; 

        if( wp_mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $message ) ) {
            // the message was sent...
            echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
        } else {
            // the message was not sent...
            echo 'The message was not sent!';
        };



//      wp_mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $message );
        header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
        echo json_encode( array("AJAX" => "Success") );
        die();

    }
}





error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

I'm getting a response of `the message was not sent! AJAX: "Success"`.

Why my function isn't working? 
Do I have to include something in my php file?
I var_dumped the parameters that I get from ajax, the are all displayed fine in the response with a status code of `Status Code:200 OK`.

Comment: Just upload simple mail script on your server and run this script through browser. if this script run successfully then something wrong with your code otherwise mail function doesn't enable on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a package called "PostFix" which is responsible for sending emails from an Ubuntu server (which is the servers Linux I use), and it solved the problem!